# Ubuntuphone Aquaris E 4.5 How to view hidden files in the home folder via MTP?

Tags: usb, ubuntu-touch, mtp

When I connect my Ubuntuphone Aquaris E 4.5 with my Ubuntu 14.04.2 PC I can see all folders in the phone's home directory but no hidden files/folders like .local/share/..
This is annoying because many apps expect data in .local/share, e.g. Ebook files for the BERU reader app.

I already updated to the latest MTPlib. Is there a way to view the hidden folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot view all files in the home folder via MTP. Only the special media folders are exposed over MTP, and so you can only transfer files (music, photos, videos, etc…) into those directories.